# Why does the glassfish server only load a bean after it has been restarted?

Tags: java, java-ee-7, glassfish-4, glassfish-4.1

When the rtu.smallview.xhtml action event is triggered it requests info from the java bean, from the database select and hands it back to the xhtml.

The xhtml was not displaying the data from the database, so I added breakpoints in the java bean to figure out what was going wrong, but when the program loaded it never hit the breakpoint in the bean.

The server output is saying this when the program is loaded:

```
Info:   WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from Beans.RTU.RTU_SmallView_Bean because of underlying class loading error: Type pojo.rtu.RTU_unit not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
```

So I stopped the server, clean and built the project again, and when it runs for the first time it loads the bean, the information is retrieved and displayed. Though if I clean and build the project again, when it runs the second time it displays the same WELD-000119 error.

I copy and pasted just the code to make the RTU section run to a new project and the server doesn't ever throw this error, and it works every time the bean is requested and every time the server is started.

Edit 1:
When I restart NetBeans and Clean and Build the project after it starts it says this:

```
Note: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OIUSA_1\src\java\Beans\RTU\RTU_SmallView_Bean.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

This is the only java class it says this about, so here is the code I used for that class:

```
package Beans.RTU;

import Database.RTU.RTU_SmallView_Select;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import pojo.rtu.RTU_unit;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
@Named(value = "rtu_SmallView_Bean")
@RequestScoped
public class RTU_SmallView_Bean {

    public RTU_SmallView_Bean() {
        try {
            RTU_SmallView_Select selectData;
            selectData = new RTU_SmallView_Select();
            this.smallViewList = selectData.getData();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    List<RTU_unit> smallViewList = new ArrayList();
    String unit_type;
    int unit_number;
    String rig_name;
    String location_name;

    public List<RTU_unit> getSmallViewList() {
        return smallViewList;
    }

    public void setSmallViewList(List<RTU_unit> smallViewList) {
        this.smallViewList = smallViewList;
    }

    public String getUnit_type() {
        return unit_type;
    }

    public void setUnit_type(String unit_type) {
        this.unit_type = unit_type;
    }

    public int getUnit_number() {
        return unit_number;
    }

    public void setUnit_number(int unit_number) {
        this.unit_number = unit_number;
    }

    public String getRig_name() {
        return rig_name;
    }

    public void setRig_name(String rig_name) {
        this.rig_name = rig_name;
    }

    public String getLocation_name() {
        return location_name;
    }

    public void setLocation_name(String location_name) {
        this.location_name = location_name;
    }
}
```

My project structure is as follows:

Sources:

1. `Beans.RTU.RTU_SmallView_Bean.java`
2. `Database.RTU.RTU_SmallView_Select.java`
3. `pojo.rtu.RTU_unit.java`

Webpages:

1. `rtu.rtu_smallview.xhtml`

I am thinking it has something to do with the actual server, but I'm not sure where to start looking for this error. If you would like to see the actual code for the beans and what not, let me know and I'll edit the question with all the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved, the file `RTU_Unit.java` was in a folder called `pojo.rtu`. I deleted the folder, made it again with a new name `pojo.rtus`, refactored the file `RTU_Unit.java` for the new folder and the problem has gone away.